# Discord.py Get the channel name from a Json file

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

I want to get the channel name from a Json file.
But I always get the channel name along with the server ID.
How can I just get the name of the channel?

**Code:**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('channel.json', 'r') as f:
        jchannel = json.load(f)

    jchannel[str(message.guild.id)] # What should I change?

    print(f"{jchannel}") # Result = "823878792563916810": "826875862980755476"
```

**Json:**

{
"823878792563916810(Server ID)" : "826875862980755476(Channel ID)"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, your actual JSON is

```
jchannel = { "823878792563916810" : "826875862980755476"}
```

if this is the only data in the jchannel variable, then you can add

```
print(jchannel[list(jchannel)[0]])
```